# System of differential equations using matrix methods

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Im trying to solve these differential equations but I’m having great difficulty.
$$3x’+y’+5x-y=2e^{-t} + 4e^{-3t}$$
$$x’+4y’-2x+7y=-3e^{-t}+5e^{-3t}$$
$$x=y=0, t=0$$

(I would be appreciative for any help grasping an intuitive understanding as to why as well as how.)

My initial idea was to eliminate y’ from one equation, and x’ from the other. This got it into a form I was familiar with solving. However I had little success getting the answer from there.

Comment: Possible strategy: Laplace transforms. You could also maybe try to generalize an integrating factor.

Comment: I think I see one way of doing it, but it would be extremely messy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the method as summarised in this [note](https://rc476.user.srcf.net/de/des_sheet4_q9.pdf) (by [@Chappers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/221811/chappers)), you can start by writing the equations in matrix form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 \\ 1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\ y'
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
-5 & 1 \\ 2 & -7
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\ -3
\end{pmatrix}e^{-t} +
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\ 5
\end{pmatrix}e^{-3t}
$$
Multiply by $\begin{pmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{11}\begin{pmatrix} 4 & -1 \\ -1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$ to get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\ y'
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 \\ 1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ -1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-t} +
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-3t}
$$

Solving the unforced equation we find that $\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = -3$ and $\lambda_2 = -1$ and corresponding eigenvectors $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, thus our complementary solution is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_c \\ y_c
\end{pmatrix} =
A\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ -1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-3t} +
B\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-t}
$$
Note here that the forcing can be written in terms of these complementary solutions, i.e.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ -1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-t} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ -1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-3t}e^{2t}
\text{ and }
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-3t} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-t}e^{-2t}
$$
This is *particularly* nice. We have no resonance and to find the particular solution we can simply integrate $e^{2t}$ and $e^{-2t}$ to get $\frac{1}{2}e^{2t}$ and $-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2t}$ respectively, and the particular solution would be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_p \\ y_p
\end{pmatrix} =
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ -1
\end{pmatrix}e^{2t}e^{-3t} -
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-2t}e^{-t} =
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ -1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-t} -
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-3t}
$$
Finally putting all of this together, and using the initial condition $x(0) = y(0) = 0$, we get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_c \\ y_c
\end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_p \\ y_p
\end{pmatrix} =
-\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ -1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-3t} +
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-t} + 
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ -1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-t} -
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-3t}
$$
the solution of the system.